# Error: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent "GestureHandlerRootView" in the "UIManager"

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler, uimanager

I am getting this error when I execute Release variant of app and just Android. It doesnt happen on Android Debug mode and neither on iOS. The Splash screen show until the js is loaded, then it crash. When I dismiss the error message the Splash screen is still there.

I tried to reinstall node_modules, read the react-native-gesture-handler documentation and other obvious stuff. The Android Release app keeps crashing on that same error. They say it can be related to expo-cli, but I dont use Expo.

[image]

Do you have any ideas please? Thank you very much.

This is my App.js.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex: 1}}></View>
      {/*<AppRoot />*/}
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}
```

I expect the app would load correctly.

Comment: Try if solutions mentioned here works : https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/238